Flink checkpoint slow/stuck
I have a Pyflink program with checkpointing configured. However, checkpointing sometimes gets stuck or timeout.
I am mainly checking the Flink dashboard, and some of the subtasks are not acknowledging the checkpoint requests.
Since each operator is only keeping a small amount of state, I would expect checkpointing to complete much faster. Any help is much appreciated. I have attached a minimal example of what I have been doing.
Thank you
import time
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.common import Configuration, WatermarkStrategy
from pyflink.datastream.functions import FlatMapFunction
from pyflink.datastream import CheckpointingMode
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.number_seq import NumberSequenceSource
from pyflink.datastream.functions import RuntimeContext
from pyflink.datastream.state import ValueStateDescriptor

PRODUCER_PARALLELISM = 1
CONSUMER_PARALLELISM = 1

NUM_TASKS = 16 * 5 * 10000
TIME_UNIT = 0.5

class Producer(FlatMapFunction):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = None

    def open(self, runtime_context: RuntimeContext):
        self.task_info = runtime_context.get_task_name_with_subtasks()
        self.task_index = runtime_context.get_index_of_this_subtask()
        self.attempt_number = runtime_context.get_attempt_number()

        descriptor = ValueStateDescriptor(
            "average",
            Types.INT(),
        )
        self.count = runtime_context.get_state(descriptor)
        print(f"Opened Producer {self.task_info} with index {self.task_index}")

    def flat_map(self, value):
        self.count.update((self.count.value() or 0) + 1)
        time.sleep(TIME_UNIT)
        print(f"count: {self.count.value()}, {value}")
        cnt = 0
        while cnt < 10000:
            cnt += 1
        yield value

def run_flink(env):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    number_source = NumberSequenceSource(0, NUM_TASKS)
    ds = env.from_source(
        source=number_source,
        watermark_strategy=WatermarkStrategy.for_monotonous_timestamps(),
        source_name="file_source",
        type_info=Types.LONG(),
    ).set_parallelism(1)
    ds = ds.key_by(lambda x: x % PRODUCER_PARALLELISM)
    ds = ds.flat_map(Producer(), output_type=Types.PICKLED_BYTE_ARRAY()).set_parallelism(
        PRODUCER_PARALLELISM
    )

    env.execute("Example")
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"Time: {end - start:.4f}s")

def run_experiment():
    config = Configuration()
    config.set_string("restart-strategy.type", "fixed-delay")
    config.set_string("restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts", "3")
    config.set_string("restart-strategy.fixed-delay.delay", "10000ms")
    config.set_string("state.backend.type", "hashmap")
    config.set_string(
        "state.checkpoints.dir",
        "file:///home/ubuntu/.../flink/flink-checkpoints",
    )

    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment(config)
    env = env.enable_checkpointing(5000, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    run_flink(env)

def main():
    run_experiment()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I am using flink-1.20.0. I am seeing on the Flink dashboard that Source: file_source -> _stream_key_by_map_operator has been acknowledged, but not FlatMap.

The NumberSequenceSource is a bounded source (it generates a finite stream of elements). As such, the workflow will be running in BATCH mode, and thus there are no checkpoints (see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/execution_mode/#checkpointing). So I'm not sure what you're reporting when you said that checkpoints weren't being acknowledged.

@kkrugler Bounded sources can run in streaming mode -- and do, by default.

Hi David - thanks, my bad. I always run my jobs with RuntimeExecutionMode.AUTOMATIC, so I always see BATCH mode being used automatically when all the sources are bounded.

I believe the main issue is that you have a 0.5 second delay (time.sleep) for every element being processed by your flat_map. This will create significant backpressure, which will delay when the checkpoint barrier will reach your function. If your flat_map is actually going to take that much time to process each record, you probably want to enable unaligned checkpoints.
Separately, you don't have a sink after your flat_map. Flink will still run your operator, even though you don't have a terminal sink in the graph, but for cleanliness at least put a DiscardingSink after the flat_map.
